# React native 0.69.1 I am facing issue 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'

Tags: react-native, react-proptypes, react-native-snap-carousel, react-native-fast-image

**Error**:

**deprecated-react-native-prop-types**

**"react-native": "0.69.1",---- this error comes only in the latest version of react-native**

```
I am facing this issues when I installed any of this library
-react-native-snap-carousel
-react-native-fast-image
```

> Requiring module
> "node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/index.js", which threw an
> exception: Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from
> React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from
> 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.

Answer (score 2):

open files

```
./node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/carousel/Carousel.js 
./node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/Pagination/Pagination.js
./node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/Pagination/PaginationDot.js
./node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/ParallaxImage/ParallaxImage.js
```

edit

```
import { ... ,ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
```

to

```
import { ... } from 'react-native';
import {ViewPropTypes} from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

it will work...

Comment: and then you should patch this package using patch-package so if you do yarn install or npm install again or one of your teammates clone the project he won't be facing the same problem

Comment: Also follow comment to avoid occurring again

Answer (score 0):

**This is a mistake of the old npm packages, and if the project is alive, then the developers fix it in new versions. And maybe this error will go away when you update the package to a newer one.**

> I found the solution for this error  install typescript package should
> also install type definitions which resolve the error
> 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' for snap crousel library

```
$ npm install --save @types/react-native-snap-carousel
    
         **THIS IS WORKING PERFECT FOR ME**
```

I PREFER TO FOLLOW THE FIRST APPROACH

> **OR you can follow different approach**

find ViewPropTypes import in the node modules in which library this gives error
delete import this file from 'react-native' and create new import

```
import {ViewPropTypes} from 'react-native';
import {ViewPropTypes} from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

and its also work good but when you install new package or npm install again you have to do this steps againn for the libraries which gives same error

Comment: I could not find any import for ViewPropTypes

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer
install this package  [deprecated-react-native-prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deprecated-react-native-prop-types/v/2.2.0) and if u install a new package search for this replace the below modules. these are the changes for  `node_modules/react-native/index.js`

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/index.js b/node_modules/react-native/index.js
index d59ba34..1bc8c9d 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native/index.js
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/index.js
@@ -435,32 +435,16 @@ module.exports = {
   },
   // Deprecated Prop Types
   get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
-    invariant(
-      false,
-      'ColorPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
-        "ColorPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
-    );
+    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ColorPropType;
   },
   get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
-    invariant(
-      false,
-      'EdgeInsetsPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
-        "EdgeInsetsPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
-    );
+    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').EdgeInsetsPropType;
   },
   get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
-    invariant(
-      false,
-      'PointPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
-        "PointPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
-    );
+    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').PointPropType;
   },
   get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
-    invariant(
-      false,
-      'ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
-        "ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
-    );
+    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
   },
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

> Install @4.0.0-beta.6 version

```
npm install -save react-native-snap-carousel@4.0.0-beta.6
```